# subdifferential of a convex multivariate function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

I want to calculate the subgradient of the following function:
$$f(w, b) = \max \{0, v(w^T u + b)\}+ \rho\|w\|_{l^1}$$
where $u\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $v\in \mathbb{R}$ are given, $w \in \mathbb{R^n}$ values and $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$.

I guess we have to divide it into three cases :

- if $0< v(w^T u + b)$: so $f(w, b) = v(w^T u + b)+ \rho\|w\|_{l^1}$ then:

$$\partial f(w, b) = \bigl(\begin{matrix}
uv + \rho s\\ v \end{matrix}\bigr)$$
where $s_i = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 1 \ &, \text{if} \  w_i >0 \\  
-1  &,\text{if} \  w_i < 0 \\ 
-1 or 1  &,\text{if} \  w_i = 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

- if $0 > v(w^T u + b)$:
  $$\partial f(w, b) =  \bigl(\begin{matrix}
   \rho s\\ 0 \end{matrix}\bigr)$$
  $s$ as above.
- if $0 = v(w^T u + b)$ :  either of above two cases.

The subdifferential is the convex hull of all subgradients. Would the convex hull of the above functions be as below?
$$\partial f(w,b) = \Big\{ \alpha \begin{pmatrix} uv \\ v \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} s \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : \alpha \in [0,1]\Big\}$$

Comment: If $0 = v (w^T u + b)$ the subdifferential is not just either of the two previous cases but any $\lambda \begin{pmatrix} uv \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} s \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: do you mean the subgradient for the 3rd case , right? and what would be the convex hull of all these subgradients?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the 3rd case. I don't think I understand your last point, though - the subdifferential is already a convex set, so taking a convex hull would not change it.

Comment: In the above case the subgradient of the sum is the sum of the subgradients.